# Update bottom view of uipagecollectionview's parent page

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have UIViewController ABC, UIPageViewController PQR, UIViewController XYZ

ABC has PQR with that it loads XYZ,

Now ABC has a footer which has to be reflected on click of button in XYZ.

See screenshot in [HERE](http://pasteboard.co/1NZGsMtS.png)

Here Order Now Buttons are in XYZ, and the Bottom red color bar is in PQR how can i reflect values there.

I Hope i am clear with question, let me know your doubts i will explain again

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can pass information from your XYZ class to your PQR class. You could simply keep a reference to PQR in XYZ, so when your button is pressed it can report this action to PQR.

You can also make use of various methods of passing information between classes indirectly. Take a look at my answer and the other answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030928/proper-way-to-handle-data-persistence-flow-with-navigation-controllers/31031309#31031309) for some examples.

Comment: Will the protocol delegate method be useful in this case?

Comment: It could be yeah. You could define a protocol for your pages to communicate with the UIPageViewController when buttons are pressed or any other information you might need to pass.